# ASP.NET CORE Model binding: Why the getter of DTO is get called by runtime before the value is set?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to use the getter to valid the property of DTO, If the property is invalid the exception is thrown, the sample code as follow:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }


    [HttpPost("test")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Foo f)
    {
        return Ok(f.Bar.Count == 1);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private List<string> _bar;
    public List<string> Bar
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bar == null || _bar.Count == 0) throw new System.Exception("at lease one element is required!");
            return _bar;
        }
        set
        {
            _bar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

use the curl to debug the api

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast/test2' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
    "Baz":"HelloWorld"
}'
```

during the API debugging, I observed that the setter is get called with an empty value of list, even if the corresponding input has value, and then was the getter. As a result, the getter thrown an exception due to the empty list.

It seem that the model binding behavior has some differences between `enumerable` type and `non-enumerable` type ( if I changed the `Bar` from `List<string>` into `string`, I would get the value in the setter);

Question:

1. Is there any way to configure asp.net core to bind the property of `enumerable` type in the way of `non-enumerable` type, I would like to do the validation in the getter instead of other place

Comment: Normally for complex objects from the request's body Asp.Net Core uses a formatter, not a binder to deserialize the action method's parameters. You can define your own custom formatted that overrides the rules of the default one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#:~:text=ASP.NET%20Core%20MVC%20supports,formatters%20for%20JSON%20and%20XML. But in general I'm not sure that the thing you are trying to achieve i.e. validation in a property getter is a good practice.

Comment: @AntonKovachev From above code, validation in getter not work,you could have a try

Comment: Validation should be performed on the *setter*, not getter. The whole point of validating a property is to ensure it doesn't get an invalid value. Why allow an invalid value to be set only to break any code that tries to use or even inspect that value?

Comment: A meaningful validation would be to check for null or empty in the setter with eg `_bar = value?.Count >0 ? value : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Bar));`. In recent C# versions `throw` can be part of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

In your request model `Foo`, you assert that `Bar` is going to be a collection of strings (e.g., an array). However, in your curl request, you are setting `Bar` to a single string instead of an array *containing* one string.

Instead, you should use
`curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast/test2' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{ "Bar": ["HelloWorld"] }'`.

If you want to accept either a string or an array for `Bar`, then you cannot use your DTO class with `[FromBody]`. Instead, your will have to write your own logic to determine the type of data in the request body and then manually parse the JSON data into the appropriate model.